# locate getting corrupted frequently on MAC Mojave

Tags: mojave

I frequently use locate on my MAC to search for files or configuration/settings of applications (Ex : `locate "pgadmin4.db"`). But I get error as shown below.

```
locate: locate database header corrupt, bigram char outside 0, 32-127: -1
```

I've seen this error on my friends's MAC as well. So I have started using `find` utility. But `locate` is much more convenient. I'm not sure if i'm doing anything wrong or there's some issue which i don't understand. And how do I fix it?

Comment: When do you get this error?

Comment: There's no specific event i guess. I just wanted to search for postgres config file on my MAC and i used locate just to find this error.

Comment: My friend told me that restarting his MAC solved the issue. But mine is not fixed.